# Loading part of an image in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I would like to load part of an image into opencv for processing. The image I want to use is too large to load as one chunk. Is this possible using the existing opencv library?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

what is the image format?

Opencv uses libjpg, libpng etc to read standard image formats. If it's a simple format that you can parse yourself then you could read blocks of a file into parts of a cv::mat image easily